# Follow through on it

Tags: word-usage, usage

> "No, the admin wants me to have a tutor from within the school. I think it's stupid, but they want me to be involved more because they think it will give me the confidence to do better by having support from a peer. It's a huge load of bullshit, but I **just might have to follow through on it.**"

Is the use of "follow through on" correct here? Shouldn't it be "**but I guess I might just have to go along with it.**"

I mean doesn't "follow through with/on something" mean something along the lines of "completing something"? As in:

> She followed through with the plan.
>
> You need to follow it through.

Or something in sports related to completing the motion after hitting the ball etc. (I've read this phrase being in tennis a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

> **[to follow through](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/follow-through)**: to continue something until it is completed.
> *The city has raised the money for more teachers – now it has to follow through and hire them*.

and

> **[to go along](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-along)**: to agree or be willing to accept something.
> *The president would not feel obligated to go along with a deal he didn't like.*

which means both can be used in your context, leaving it up to personal preference. I myself would use *to go with*.

Comment: Oh....yeah that's an alternative too!! It totally slipped my mind.

Comment: But, "go along with", or "go with" mean "accepting something", but "follow along with it" means "continuing something until it's completed", aren't they a bit different?

Comment: As I interpret it, in your context, "accepting something" (accepting having a tutor from within the school) and "continuing something until it's completed" (continue have the tutor until the admin thinks it's no longer necessary [completed]) mean the same. They **are** not the same, but in *this* context, they **mean** the same.